# Applications of logarithmic functions in shapes and geometries

Tags: functions, logarithms, computational-geometry

As I understand this logarithmic functions are a family of functions where the equation for $f(x)$ is written like so

$$\begin{align}
f(x) = & \log_{a} x \\
& \mathtt{where\ }a\mathtt{\ is\ the\ independent\ variable}
\end{align}
$$

Now I'm curious about general applications of this kind of functions in algebra and geometry, if I'm not mistaking they have some nice properties regarding proportions and they are useful to build shapes ? I don't know I'm quite confused on this one; Some can explain why this kind of functions are popular ?

---

$\mathtt{Edit :}$

[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/254320/84528) is an interesting little compact explanation for example, but it lacks a real explanation and some examples .

Answer (score 1):

It is not totally clear what you are asking, but one nice property is that if $a$ and $b$ are positive but not $1$ then $$\log_a x = k \log_b x$$ for some constant $k$ and all positive $x$.  So logarithms to any base are scaled versions of logarithms to other bases.

In fact $k=\log_a b = \dfrac{1}{\log_b a} = \dfrac{\log_c b}{\log_c a}$.

Comment: there was a vague reference to this in some article I read about harmonics and how harmonics can be "extracted" from shapes and geometrical figures; but my memory about this is, again, foggy, this is the kind of "patterns" I'm looking for. There also was some reference to logarithmic functions in some other articles about how to build regular polygons or polyhedra .